# MATLAB: efficient way to run a vector input function with an array input

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, bsxfun

I have a function `HermitePCECoefficients` which takes as inputs multiple parameters, including a column vector `y`, and outputs a column vector `Coefficients`, the same length as `y`:

```
Coefficients=HermitePCECoefficients(grid,weights,indices,y,mu,sigma,normalized)
```

Suppose now that `y` is not a column vector, but a 2D array (matrix), and I want to run `HermitePCECoefficients` on each of its columns, storing the corresponding outputs in a array. Doing it with a `for` loop is simple and clear, but it takes forever:

```
Coefficients=zeros(size(y));
for i=1:size(y,2)
    Coefficients(:,i)=HermitePCECoefficients(grid,weights,indices,y(:,i),mu,sigma,normalized);
end
```

Thus, I put `bsxfun` to the job. Since `bsxfun` only works with binary functions, I created a "dummy" binary function f, which is really only a function of a single argument:

```
f=@(a,b) HermitePCECoefficients(grid,weights,indices,a,mu,sigma,normalized);
```

Then used `bsxfun` this way:

```
Coefficients=bsxfun(f,y,omega_f);
```

This works fine, and it's much faster than the `for` loop (don't worry about `omega_f`, it's just a vector whose length corresponds to the number of columns in `y`).

Question 1: do you think this is the right way to use `bsxfun` in this context?

Question 2: maybe a better solution would be to directly modify `HermitePCECoefficients`, so that it could take a generic array `y` as input. Inside the function, this is the only line which requires `y` to be a column vector:

```
Coefficients(i)=dot(weights,y.*Psi)/norm;
```

`weights` and `Psi` are two column vectors, so if I pass an array `y`, MATLAB complains. Any suggestions on how to modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2 seems better (but only testing will tell). Just replace

```
dot(weights,y.*Psi)/norm
```

by

```
sum(bsxfun(@times, weights.*Psi, y)/norm)
```

or (probably faster)

```
(weights.*Psi).'*y / norm
```

Either of the above is equivalent to computing the vector `[ dot(weights,y(:,1).*Psi)/norm, dot(weights,y(:,2).*Psi)/norm, ... ]` for an arbitrary number of columns of `y`. Each entry of this vector is the result for a column of `y`.

Comment: Thanks! `dot(weights,y.*Psi)/norm` is a numerical integration, where `weights` are the weights of the quadrature rule, and `y.*Psi` is the integrand evaluated at the quadrature abscissae. So, for purely aesthetic reasons, I'd have preferred to perform the multiplication between `y` and `Psi` before , and then the dot product with `weights`. But I understand that's just nit-picking, so I selected your answer.

Comment: Ps the reason why `sum` isn't needed in your second solution, i.e., why you didn't write something like `sum((weights.*Psi).'*y)/norm`, is that the product between `(weights.*Psi)` and `y` is a matrix product, instead than elementwise product, right? So a sum is already implied.

Comment: @DeltaIV Yes, the second option is matrix multiplication, which includes a sum

Answer (score 1):

You could use `repmat` on `weights` and `Psi` to replicate the vectors across the columns of y:

```
nc = size(y,2);
Coefficients = dot(repmat(weights,1,nc), y.*repmat(Psi,1,nc))/norm;
```